# Calculate MAX by subcategory Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Hello I m newbie in dax ,

I want to calculate the max of value by subcategory and category.

it s like Max(Max(subcategory)category ) this example explain what I need .
Category    Subcategory value

animal  lion    5

food    tomato  4

food    potato  6

animal  dog 5

plants  flower  2

Category    Max value

animal  5 ( if we have 2 subcategory with same value he choose randomly one )

food    6 ( potato )

plants  2

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dRLD.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI, you do not have to calculate anything. You can simply use a visual to get teh result you want. Import the data, drag the table-visual on the report. Drag the Category and the value on the table.

As last step, set the value to the Max and you are done..

Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aldert for your response, I want it as mesure or colum to calculate the average for each category in a period of time and display it in barchart